# Images loaded from URI have black Background

Tags: android

I am trying to load PNG which has transparent background.

```
mImageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                ImageThumbnailAdapter.IMAGE_PROJECTION, null, null,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

Projection:

```
public static final int IMAGE_ID_COLUMN = 0;
    public static final int IMAGE_NAME_COLUMN = 1;
```

Method for loading:

```
private static Bitmap loadThumbnail(ContentResolver cr, Uri uri) {
    return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
            cr, ContentUris.parseId(uri), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, sBitmapOptions);
}
```

Setting in View:

```
            Bitmap bitmapOld = loadThumbnail(mArgs.mContentResolver, mArgs.mUri);

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmapOld.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out  );
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

            Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmapOld.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

//          Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
            canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

//This drawabl is coming black in Background. 
                final Bitmap bmpfinal = mutableBitmap;
```

Comment: So can you please tell me that is that a web uri or simple like you stored in the local system?

Comment: local file system.

Comment: just go through this link once https://github.com/hiteshsahu/AwesomeAndroid-Gallery

Comment: all images are png which you want to show?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
return MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver‌​(), uri);
```

i hope it may solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) will help you out to resolve your issue, go through provided link and integrate picasso.